# Git Segragate Data between multiple remotes

Tags: git

I have been working on Code Pulled from an Open Source github project.
I've been working on it for a while now.  I've been storing it in a private bitBucket repository.  Unfortunately early on I added some sensitive data to my private version of the code.  In the latest versions of the code I manually ripped that sensitive data back out.  I would like to push a clean version of my code to github from my private repo, but only the latest version of the code.

Is there a way to push just the most recent version of the code from my Repo without pushing all the past commits with the sensitive information still in the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various different ways to do this. The simplest ways that I can think of are these.

1. Make a new branch. Then make one commit with your latest code in it. Just push that one branch up to gitHub.

   `rm -Rf *
   git checkout <your_original_branch> -- .
   git add .
   git commit -am 'my work'`
2. Clone a whole new repo, make your branch, and do a very similar thing.

   `rm -Rf *
   cp -a /path/to/your/work .
   git add .
   git commit -am 'my work'`

The second solution is uglier, IMHO, but it has the advantage that your new repo has no sensitive info in it at all so there's no chance you can push the wrong branch and publish sensitive info.

I'm sure somebody else will respond with cleverer and more git-y solutions, but these are simple.

Comment: Believe it or not those were the first two options I had come with, but I was worried either **Option 1** would accidentally send the history anyway. or I would mess up the commands somehow for option 1, and send the history anyway.  For **Option 2** I agree about it not being very *git-y* I had a co-worker suggest a complicated rebase based solution.